# Adobe Animate Missing Export Compliance ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption False

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, adobe-animate

Anyone know how to remove the annoying Apple Missing Export Compliance?

I have tried adding **ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption** to the app's XML config file (name-app.xml).

```
<key>ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption</key><false/>
```

Has no effect.

Comment: Well that _should_ be the correct answer as far as I can tell. Perhaps it's a bug of the specific AIR Version you're using, have you tried down/upgrading to another AIR Version?

Comment: @DodgerThud yeah that's what I thought, I'm using a "stable" version of AIR (don't really want to start changing SDK's at this point). But will check if there's anything newer stable. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to get it working, I moved the **ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption** `Key` to the bottom of the `Key` list. Inside the `InfoAdditions` and seems to be working now:

```
<iPhone>
    <InfoAdditions><![CDATA[

            <!--
            <key>....</key>
            <key>....</key>
            -->

            <key>ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption</key><false/>

    ]]></InfoAdditions>
</iPhone>
```